# How to PUT to contact in Insight.ly?

Tags: node.js

My code in Node.js looks like the following.

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: "GET",
  gzip: true,
  headers: "Authorization": "Basic MY_API_KEY_BASE64",
  url: "https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Contacts?email=AN_EMAIL_ADDRESS",
}, function(err, res, body) {
  var contact = JSON.parse(body);
  contact.CUSTOMFIELDS.push({
    "TESTING_TESTING": "TESTING",
    "FIELD_VALUE": "Pizza"
  });

  request({
    method: "PUT",
    gzip: true,
    headers: "Authorization": "Basic MY_API_KEY_BASE64",
    url: "https://api.insight.ly/v2.1/Contacts",
    json: contact
  }, function(err, res, body) {
    // Always returns a 400 with the body equal to "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: key"
```

Clearly the error message they return isn't correct. Does anyone have experience with Insight.ly's API and been able to figure out how to update contacts?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing! Ever figure it out?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?